# Find the Run Time of Select Ruby Code

Tags: ruby, runtime, sleep

### Problem

Howdy guys, so I want to find the run time of a block of code in Ruby, but I am not entirely sure as to how I could do it. I want to run some code, and then output how long it took to run that code because I have a super huge program and the run time changes a lot. I want to make sure it always has a consistent run time (I could do it by sleeping it for a fraction of a second) but that isn't my problem. I want to find out how long the run time actually is so the program can know if it needs to slow things down or speed things up.

### My Thoughts

So, I have an idea as to how it could work. I have never used `Time` in ruby but I have an idea as to how I could use that. I could have a `variable` equal to the time (in milliseconds) and then another `variable` that I make at the end of the code block that does it again, and then I just subtract them, but I have (1) never used `Time` and (2) I don't actually know if that is the best way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby has the [Benchmark](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) module for timing how long things take. I've never used this outside of seeing if a method is taking too long to run, etc. in development, not sure if this is 'recommended' for production code or for keeping things above a minimum runtime (as it sounds like you might be doing), but take a look and see how it feels for your use case.

It also sounds like you might be interested in the [Timeout](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html) module as well (for making sure things don't take longer than a set amount of time).

If you really have a use case for making sure something takes a *minimum* amount of time, timing the code (either using a Benchmark method or just Time or another solution) and then `sleep` the difference  is the only thing that comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. Look at your watch (`Time.now`) and remember the time, run the code, look at your watch again, subtract.

```
t0 = Time.now
# your block of code
puts Time.now - t0
```

Answer (score 0):

[http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html 
You want to to use the Time object. (Time Docs)

For example,

```
  start = Time.now
 # code to time
 finish = Time.now

 diff = finish - start
```

diff would be in seconds, as a floating point number.

EDIT: end is reserved.
or you can use
    require 'benchmark'

```
 def foo
  time = Benchmark.measure {
   code to test
   }
```

puts time.real #or save it to logs
end
Sample output:

```
   2.2.3 :001 > foo
   5.230000   0.020000   5.250000 (  5.274806)
```

Values are CPU time, system time, total and real elapsed time.
[http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html#method-c-bm
Source: Ruby docs.